# Creating an Ajax Chained/Dependent Dropdown list for categories and tags on Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create 2 dependent dropdown lists for WP. The section I am trying to create is for recipes so I hope my example is more helpful than the general question.

We have recipes broken down into 2 sections: type of meal (appetizer, main course, dessert etc.) and ingredients (rice, poultry, milk etc.). The type of meal is a category, and ingredients are tags. I am trying to create an ajax code so people can filter our recipes by categories (ie appetizers) or tags (ie chicken), or categories and tags together (ie appetizers that have chicken).

Visitors will start on a category page so ideally the first dropdown should recognize the category users are currently in and list that category by default. The 2nd dropdown's default can say something like "Select Ingredient" and once clicked, it should only list ingredients that are available in that category. So for example, if there are no appetizers with vanilla, vanilla should not be available as a tag in the 2nd dropdown.

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626930/dynamically-filter-wordpress-posts-with-dropdown-menu-using-php-and-ajax) to something I found to get me started, but I don't know how to make it specifically target the category and tag.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Using Ajax to execute a WordPress function call and manipulate the returned value. See this plugin in WordPress StackExchange for [Unattaching images from a post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/54822/12615).

The name of what you describe is "chained menu" or "chained selection", see this tutorial [Simple chained combobox plugin for jQuery](https://web.archive.org/web/20130430040427/http://codeassembly.com/Simple-chained-combobox-plugin-for-jQuery/).

> Very simple chained selects plugin for jQuery with JSON processing and callback feature, chain multiple selects with ease.