# TypeError $.urlGetVars is not a function in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, typeerror, drop-down-menu

I am getting

TypeError: $.urlGetVars is not a function in my WordPress Site.

return $.urlGetVars()[name];

I got script from [Dynamically filter WordPress posts by selectbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626930/dynamically-filter-wordpress-posts-with-dropdown-menu-using-php-and-ajax)
For Filtering the posts by selecting author in drop down box.

I am getting this Error after added jQuery slider.
Got jQuery slider from [enter link description here](http://www.mybloggertricks.com/2011/06/jquery-image-slider-for-blogger-v3.html)

Comment: any other erros in the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress runs jQuery in [no conflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) which means that unless you've wrapped your code in a [no conflict wrapper](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) you're going to need to use `jQuery` instead of `$`.